# Cannot retrieve Magento Attribute Frontend Label

Tags: magento, attributes, frontend

I successfully get the value of any attribute with: $product_data->getBrennwert(); where "brennwert" is the attribute code.
But for some reason i cant get the Frontend-Label:

```
$product_data->getResource()->getAttribute('brennwert')->getFrontendLabel()
```

Normally this works every time. Seems i miss something this time.
I tried it this way too:

```
$product_data->getResource()->getAttribute('brennwert')->getFrontend()->getLabel($product_data)
```

But this just gives me just the attribute code "brennwert".

this is my productcollection:

```
$product_data = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect(array(
    'name', 
    'description',
    'product_url', 
    'thumbnail', 
    'price', 
    'special_price', 
    'group_price', 
    'short_description', 
    'weight', 
    'url_key', 
    'brennwert', 
    'brennwert_prozent', 
    'zucker', 
    'zucker_prozent', 
    'fett', 
    'fett_prozent', 
    'fett_gesaettigt', 
    'fett_gesaettigt_prozent', 
    'natrium', 
    'natrium_prozent',
    'naehrwerte_anmerkung'
))
->addFieldToFilter('sku',array('like'=>$sku))
->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: $product_data->getAttributeText('brennwert');

Answer (score 0):

Please  try below code

```
    $product_data = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array(
            'name', 
            'description',
            'product_url', 
            'thumbnail', 
            'price', 
            'special_price', 
            'group_price', 
            'short_description', 
            'weight', 
            'url_key', 
            'brennwert', 
            'brennwert_prozent', 
            'zucker', 
            'zucker_prozent', 
            'fett', 
            'fett_prozent', 
            'fett_gesaettigt', 
            'fett_gesaettigt_prozent', 
            'natrium', 
            'natrium_prozent',
            'naehrwerte_anmerkung'
        ))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('sku',array('like'=>$sku))

       ->getFirstItem();
    $product_data->addStoreFilter((Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
for indivisual product----

 $product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

Comment: but i dont want to get the value but the (admin) label/title!